Quiero saber como cambiar el estilo del datatables

Una duda como hago para que mi datatable tenga el estilo oscuro tambien y no solo la tabla porque al usar este codigo mi tabla esta oscura pero en las opciones de entries per page sigue en letra negra, los numeros de la pagina abajo sigue en blanco y celeste igual que las flechas


var table;

$(document).ready(function() {

  table = $('#tablaClientes').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "searching": true,
    "info": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
    "language": {
      "paginate": {
        "previous": "<",
        "next": ">"
      },
      "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ "
    },
    "order": [
      [0, 'desc']
    ]
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.8/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.8/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped table-dark" id="tablaClientes" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Dirección</th>
      <th>Teléfono</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Fecha Registro</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>




El mio se ve asi con esos colores y invisible las entries per page

¿Revisaste la documentación?

Debes agregar la versión de Datatables y Bootstrap que estás utilizando, dado que dependiendo de ellas cambia la respuesta

ya seguiste los pasos de la documentación? https://datatables.net/manual/styling/dark-mode
